# Can Mockito capture arguments of a method called multiple times?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a method that gets called twice, and I want to capture the argument of the second method call.

Here's what I've tried:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Foo> firstFooCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Foo.class);
ArgumentCaptor<Foo> secondFooCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Foo.class);
verify(mockBar).doSomething(firstFooCaptor.capture());
verify(mockBar).doSomething(secondFooCaptor.capture());
// then do some assertions on secondFooCaptor.getValue()
```

But I get a `TooManyActualInvocations` Exception, as Mockito thinks that `doSomething` should only be called once.

How can I verify the argument of the second call of `doSomething`?

Answer (score 1023, accepted):

I think it should be

```
verify(mockBar, times(2)).doSomething(...)
```

Sample from [mockito javadoc](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html):

```
ArgumentCaptor<Person> peopleCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Person.class);
verify(mock, times(2)).doSomething(peopleCaptor.capture());

List<Person> capturedPeople = peopleCaptor.getAllValues();
assertEquals("John", capturedPeople.get(0).getName());
assertEquals("Jane", capturedPeople.get(1).getName());
```

Comment: Can you capture the arguments passed to `doSomething()` in each separate invocation with this?

Comment: It should be noted that in case you do something like this: 
`Person person = new Person("John");
doSomething(person);
person.setName("Jane");
doSomething(person);`
the captured argument will be the same twice (because actually it is the same person object), so `capturedPeople.get(0).getName() == capturedPeople.get(1).getName() == "Jane"` , see also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mockito/KBRocVedYT0/5HtARMl9r2wJ.

Comment: This is nice, but how can I test two differently typed object invocations? For example ExecutorService.submit(new MyRunableImpl()); and then ExecutorService.submit(new MyAnotherRunableImpl()) ?

Comment: If one needs to handle the case described by @asmaier, I posted an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36574817/1466267

Comment: Hi @Leon, did u get the solution for the different type arguments?

Comment: For anyone still wondering about the answer to Leon's question, you'd use the common base class (`Runnable`) and, if needed, do a more specific type check on the captured argument.

Answer (score 81):

Since Mockito 2.0 there's also possibility to use static method [Matchers.argThat(ArgumentMatcher)](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html#argThat(org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher)). With the help of Java 8 it is now much cleaner and more readable to write:

```
verify(mockBar).doSth(argThat((arg) -> arg.getSurname().equals("OneSurname")));
verify(mockBar).doSth(argThat((arg) -> arg.getSurname().equals("AnotherSurname")));
```

If you're tied to lower Java version there's also not-that-bad:

```
verify(mockBar).doSth(argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<Employee>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object emp) {
            return ((Employee) emp).getSurname().equals("SomeSurname");
        }
    }));
```

Of course none of those can verify order of calls - for which you should use [InOrder](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/InOrder.html) :

```
InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mockBar);

inOrder.verify(mockBar).doSth(argThat((arg) -> arg.getSurname().equals("FirstSurname")));
inOrder.verify(mockBar).doSth(argThat((arg) -> arg.getSurname().equals("SecondSurname")));
```

Please take a look at [mockito-java8](https://github.com/szpak/mockito-java8) project which makes possible to make calls such as:

```
verify(mockBar).doSth(assertArg(arg -> assertThat(arg.getSurname()).isEqualTo("Surname")));
```

Comment: This is a nice technique.  I'm currently getting some rather cryptic output though: "Wanted but not invoked: /n mockAppender.append( <Index manager u t$$ lambda$ 5 9/ 1 3 1 9 5 1 0 1 6> );" - the arg there is a `CharSequence`.  Do you know of any way to get the report to print out the "wanted" arg properly?

Comment: @mikerodent The cryptic output can be fixed if you go the more verbose route of creating a class that implements ArgumentMatcher<T>. Overriding the toString method in your implementation will provide any message you want in the mockito test output.

Answer (score 32):

If you don't want to validate all the calls to `doSomething()`, only the last one, you can just use `ArgumentCaptor.getValue()`.  According to the [Mockito javadoc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/index.html?org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html):

*If the method was called multiple times then it returns the latest captured value*

So this would work (assumes `Foo` has a method `getName()`):

```
ArgumentCaptor<Foo> fooCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Foo.class);
verify(mockBar, times(2)).doSomething(fooCaptor.capture());
//getValue() contains value set in second call to doSomething()
assertEquals("2nd one", fooCaptor.getValue().getName());
```

Comment: is there any way to capture both the values?

Answer (score 27):

You can also use @Captor annotated ArgumentCaptor. For example:

```
@Mock
List<String> mockedList;

@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<String> argCaptor;

@BeforeTest
public void init() {
    //Initialize objects annotated with @Mock, @Captor and @Spy.
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void shouldCallAddMethodTwice() {
    mockedList.add("one");
    mockedList.add("two");
    Mockito.verify(mockedList, times(2)).add(argCaptor.capture());

    assertEquals("one", argCaptor.getAllValues().get(0));
    assertEquals("two", argCaptor.getAllValues().get(1));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

With Java 8's lambdas, a convenient way is to use

```
org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock

when(client.deleteByQuery(anyString(), anyString())).then(invocationOnMock -> {
    assertEquals("myCollection", invocationOnMock.getArgument(0));
    assertThat(invocationOnMock.getArgument(1), Matchers.startsWith("id:"));
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to see how this is more convenient than the old way. I love good use of lambdas, but I'm not sure if this is one.

Answer (score 5):

First of all: you should always import mockito static, this way the code will be much more readable (and intuitive) - the code samples below require it to work:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

In the verify() method you can pass the ArgumentCaptor to assure execution in the test and the ArgumentCaptor to evaluate the arguments:

```
ArgumentCaptor<MyExampleClass> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyExampleClass.class);
verify(yourmock, atleast(2)).myMethod(argument.capture());

List<MyExampleClass> passedArguments = argument.getAllValues();

for (MyExampleClass data : passedArguments){
    //assertSometing ...
    System.out.println(data.getFoo());
}
```

The list of all passed arguments during your test is accessible via the argument.getAllValues() method.

The single (last called) argument's value is accessible via the argument.getValue() for further manipulation / checking or whatever you wish to do.